# How to detect that a burst of related events is done, and then emit one event

Tags: javascript, node.js, eventemitter

My first question!  I really do want to ask it right, so please help me improve it if I could have asked it better.

Here's the only question I found that seemed remotely related, but I couldn't figure out how to relate it back to what I was trying to do (their question is JQuery-specific; mine is Node.JS specific-ish [though I found a browser version of EventEmitter and was able to test in-browser as well]):  [Run function once per event burst with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448652/run-function-once-per-event-burst-with-jquery)

---

### The Question

I have a process that I know will emit a burst of events over a period of time.

To simulate this process, I've composed this code:

```
/*******************************************************/
/*         This part taken directly from               */
/*       https://nodejs.org/api/events.html            */
/*          (with addition of "burstID")               */
/* */                                               /* */
/* */ const EventEmitter = require('events');       /* */
/* */                                               /* */
/* */ class MyEmitter extends EventEmitter {}       /* */
/* */                                               /* */
/* */ const myEmitter = new MyEmitter();            /* */
/* */ myEmitter.on('event', (burstID) => {          /* */
/* */   console.log('an event occurred!', burstID); /* */
/* */ });                                           /* */
/* */                                               /* */
/*******************************************************/

const millisecondsToSustainBurst = 3000 ;
const millisecondsBetweenPossibleEventEmissions = 200 ;
const millisecondsUntilStartNextBurst = 5000 ;
const millisecondsUntilNoMoreBursts = 23000 ;

const now = new Date() ;
console.log('Time now: ' + now + '; should run until about ' + new Date(now.getTime() + millisecondsUntilNoMoreBursts)) ;

const doRandomEmitBurst = (startTimestamp, millisecondsToSustainBurst, burstID) => {
    if (Math.random() > 0.5) myEmitter.emit('event', burstID) ;
    if (
        !((new Date()) - startTimestamp > millisecondsToSustainBurst)
    ) setTimeout(() => doRandomEmitBurst(startTimestamp, millisecondsToSustainBurst, burstID), millisecondsBetweenPossibleEventEmissions) ;
}

const doRegularRandomBursts = (startTimestamp, millisecondsUntilStartNextBurst, millisecondsUntilNoMoreBursts, callback) => {
    if (
        !((new Date()) - startTimestamp > millisecondsUntilNoMoreBursts)
    ) {
        const now = new Date() ;
        console.log('Time now: ' + now + '; starting random-event burst which will run for ' + (millisecondsToSustainBurst/1000) + ' seconds.  ') ;
        setTimeout(() => doRegularRandomBursts(startTimestamp, millisecondsUntilStartNextBurst, millisecondsUntilNoMoreBursts, callback), millisecondsUntilStartNextBurst) ;
        doRandomEmitBurst(new Date(), millisecondsToSustainBurst, 'burstThatStartedAt' + now.getHours() + 'h' + now.getMinutes() + 'm' + now.getSeconds() + 's') ;
    } else callback() ;
}

doRegularRandomBursts(new Date(), millisecondsUntilStartNextBurst, millisecondsUntilNoMoreBursts, () => console.log('Done at ' + (new Date()))) ;

const myBurstDetectedEmitter = new MyEmitter() ;
// NOW, what do I do HERE to say:
// I've seen a number of events occur in a 5-second period
// Now they've stopped
// Therefore I'm going to emit a different kind of event
```

---

Now, let's say that I want to listen for these bursts to occur.

I want to make sure the burst is over before I take further action.

How would I do that?

---

### What I've tried so far

To start with, I can make a global "var" (yuck—I'd like to avoid mutables) like this:

```
var timeLastUpdated = {} ;
```

…and then…

```
function keepCheckingTimeLastUpdated(keyForUpdateCheck, callback) {
    const timestampToCheckInOneSecond = (typeof timeLastUpdated[keyForUpdateCheck] !== 'undefined' ? timeLastUpdated[keyForUpdateCheck] : (new Date())) ;
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(
            'checking if modifications to "' +
            keyForUpdateCheck +
            '" have occurred since ' +
            timestampToCheckInOneSecond
        ) ;
        if (timeLastUpdated[keyForUpdateCheck] === timestampToCheckInOneSecond) {
            delete timeLastUpdated[keyForUpdateCheck] ;
            callback() ;
        }
        else keepCheckingTimeLastUpdated(keyForUpdateCheck, callback) ;
    }, 5000) ;
}

const makeNotificationHandler = () => (keyForUpdateCheck) => {
    const timeNow = new Date() ;
    if (typeof timeLastUpdated[keyForUpdateCheck] === 'undefined') keepCheckingTimeLastUpdated(keyForUpdateCheck, () => console.log(keyForUpdateCheck + ' changed')) ;
    timeLastUpdated[keyForUpdateCheck] = timeNow ;
} ;

myEmitter.on('event', makeNotificationHandler()) ;
```

It's just that this seems to be an anti-pattern (I hope I'm using that term right).  My gut says that having a global object is the wrong approach here, and that there's a more functional-programming-like solution to be had.

---

*ONLY FOR THOSE INTERESTED:*

*(feel free to ignore for question-answering purposes)*

Added complication:  in my example code, the "burstID" would never be the same, but in the real-world example, it might be.  I'd want to wait until a certain amount of time had elapsed since the last time that "burstID" had shown up in order to figure out if the burst of changes is truly done.

For context, in the real-world application, I am setting up a "LISTEN" on a PostGres database using [node-postgres](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres).  "burstID" is a primary key in one table, and is also used as a foreign key in multiple other tables.  I am listening on all tables that use the shared key, and the message that I get back contains this key.

Comment: Pretty good first question!  Two suggestions about that.  First, you did a great job with the setup, but you should really include some of your own attempt at a solution here.  Second, the added complication and real-world context are mostly distractions.  Sorry I don't have time to give it a decent answer right now.  One suggestion: `cancelTimeout`/`setTimeout` when new related event occurs.  Use them to eventually fire your `burstCompleted` event.  Also search for `debounce` techniques.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @ScottSauyet!  I forgot, I was going to list one attempt.  I'll add that in.  I can see how the last two bits of my question as-is right now are distracting; just wanted indicate that this wasn't just a theoretical question, but I'll separate it off.

Comment: OK, question is modified, @ScottSauyet .  I'll look into `debounce` next.  Thanks!

Comment: This general approach looks workable to me.  To get rid of the global, you can store it in a closure with `keepChecking...` and `make...Handler`.  The easiest way would be to simply return the latter from an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/).

Comment: And by the way, thank you for taking the effort to consider how to ask a question appropriately for the community.  It is much appreciated!

Comment: No problem!  I like to try to do things properly, asking questions included.  :)  The problem I have with using a `var` is that, ever since reading about flow-based programming [here](http://www.jpaulmorrison.com/fbp/concepts_book.shtml)—specifically the part about "destructive storage" and the "strange use" of the equals sign—I've been very loathe to alter any variable after setting it (thus why I love the new `const` in ES6).  Maybe the way I've been thinking of it is the wrong way to think of it in this case, and maybe shielding it in a closure is just fine.  Just looking for options.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood: I thought the concern was that it was global.  My suggestion fixed only that.  And while you could use `const` rather than `var` here, that doesn't change the fact that you're mutating a value.  I am all in favor of immutable values, enough so that I started **[a fairly popular library](http://ramdajs.com)** on FP principles of immutability, composability, and pure functions.  But I'm not sure I see any way around the notion that you are trying to somehow encapsulate a changing state across multiple events; I don't think that can be made of entirely immutable functions.

Comment: OK, thanks!  I'll leave the question open for now.  If it doesn't yield other answers, I'll merge what I have above with your suggestion of encapsulation in a closure, and answer it myself.  Also, your Ramda library sounds really cool; I'll check it out!

Comment: If I have time, I'll come back to this question of mine.  These days (a whole year later), I think I would try using [ReactiveX](http://reactivex.io/) / [RxJS](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/) to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, with help from the comments above.

A big "Thank You!" to [Scott Sauyet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1243641/scott-sauyet) for his help and encouragement.

---

I've decided to create something I'm calling an "Accumulomator":  an automated accumulator.  Messages are routed to these Accumulomators, who I think of as people in a warehouse with a bin and a stopwatch.

As soon as the Accumulomator is instantiated, it starts looking at its stopwatch.  Every time the stopwatch gets to the end, the Accumulomator looks to see if it has the same pile of messages as last time.  If it's the same as last time, the Accumulomator packages up its bin of messages, hands them off to the warehouse, and retires somewhere sunny.

Full updated code is below.  I welcome any edits to improve the code.

---

```
// To test in a browser, use:
// https://github.com/Olical/EventEmitter
// …in place of const EventEmitter = require('events');

/*******************************************************/
/*         This part taken directly from               */
/*       https://nodejs.org/api/events.html            */
/*          (with addition of "burstID")               */
/* */                                               /* */
/* */ const EventEmitter = require('events');       /* */
/* */                                               /* */
/* */ class MyEmitter extends EventEmitter {}       /* */
/* */                                               /* */
/* */ const myEmitter = new MyEmitter();            /* */
/* */ myEmitter.on('event', (burstID) => {          /* */
/*      console.log('an event occurred!', burstID);    */
/* */ });                                           /* */
/* */                                               /* */
/*******************************************************/

const millisecondsToSustainBurst = 3000 ;
const millisecondsBetweenPossibleEventEmissions = 200 ;
const millisecondsUntilStartNextBurst = 5000 ;
const millisecondsUntilNoMoreBursts = 23000 ;

const now = new Date() ;
console.log('Bursts starting.  Time now: ' + now + '; should run until about ' + new Date(now.getTime() + millisecondsUntilNoMoreBursts)) ;

const doRandomEmitBurst = (startTimestamp, millisecondsToSustainBurst, burstID) => {
    if (Math.random() > 0.5) myEmitter.emit('event', burstID) ;
    if (
        !((new Date()) - startTimestamp > millisecondsToSustainBurst)
    ) setTimeout(() => doRandomEmitBurst(startTimestamp, millisecondsToSustainBurst, burstID), millisecondsBetweenPossibleEventEmissions) ;
}

const doRegularRandomBursts = (startTimestamp, millisecondsUntilStartNextBurst, millisecondsUntilNoMoreBursts, callback) => {
    if (
        !((new Date()) - startTimestamp > millisecondsUntilNoMoreBursts)
    ) {
        const now = new Date() ;
        console.log('Time now: ' + now + '; starting random-event burst which will run for ' + (millisecondsToSustainBurst/1000) + ' seconds.  ') ;
        setTimeout(() => doRegularRandomBursts(startTimestamp, millisecondsUntilStartNextBurst, millisecondsUntilNoMoreBursts, callback), millisecondsUntilStartNextBurst) ;
        doRandomEmitBurst(new Date(), millisecondsToSustainBurst, 'burstThatStartedAt' + now.getHours() + 'h' + now.getMinutes() + 'm' + now.getSeconds() + 's') ;
    } else callback() ;
}

doRegularRandomBursts(new Date(), millisecondsUntilStartNextBurst, millisecondsUntilNoMoreBursts, () => console.log('Done at ' + (new Date()))) ;


const makeAccumulomator = (config) => {
    if (typeof config !== 'object') throw new Error('Must specify configuration object.') ;
    if (typeof config.callback !== 'function') throw new Error('Must specify callback function for when the end of new messages is reached.') ;
    if (typeof config.millisecondsBetweenChecks !== 'number') throw new Error('Must specify milliseconds between checks.') ;
    if (Number.isInteger(config.millisecondsBetweenChecks) === false) throw new Error('Must specify milliseconds between checks as an integer.') ;
    if (typeof config.onStop !== 'function' && typeof config.onStop !== 'undefined') throw new Error('If defined at all, onStop must be a function.') ;

    const accumulomator = {} ;


    var accumulatedMessages = [] ;
    var stop = false ;

    const keepCheckingTimeLastUpdated = (callback) => {
        const timestampToCheckInOneSecond = (accumulatedMessages.length > 0 ? accumulatedMessages[accumulatedMessages.length - 1].timestamp : (new Date())) ;
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (stop) { if (typeof config.onStop === 'function') config.onStop() ; }
            else if (accumulatedMessages.length < 1) keepCheckingTimeLastUpdated(callback) ;
            else if (accumulatedMessages[accumulatedMessages.length - 1].timestamp === timestampToCheckInOneSecond) { stop = true ; callback() ; }
            else keepCheckingTimeLastUpdated(callback) ;
        }, config.millisecondsBetweenChecks) ;
    } ;
    keepCheckingTimeLastUpdated(config.callback) ;

    accumulomator.receiveMessage = (message) => accumulatedMessages.push({ message: message, timestamp: (new Date())}) ;

    accumulomator.stopOnNextCheck = () => {
        if (stop === true) throw new Error('Accumulomator is already stopped.') ;
        else stop = true ;
    }

    accumulomator.isActive = () => stop === false ;

    accumulomator.getAccumulatedMessages = () => accumulatedMessages ;


    return accumulomator ;

}

const makeAccumulomatorWarehouse = (config) => {
    if (typeof config !== 'object') throw new Error('Must specify configuration object.') ;
    if (typeof config.callback !== 'function') throw new Error('Must specify callback function.') ;
    if (typeof config.millisecondsBetweenChecks !== 'number') throw new Error('Must specify milliseconds between checks.') ;
    if (Number.isInteger(config.millisecondsBetweenChecks) === false) throw new Error('Must specify milliseconds between checks as an integer.') ;
    if (typeof config.messageRouter !== 'function') throw new Error('Must specify message router function.') ;
    if (typeof config.sendCallbackAccumulatedMessages !== 'undefined') if (typeof config.sendCallbackAccumulatedMessages !== 'boolean') throw new Error('Must specify whether or not to send callback accumulated messages as a boolean (if unspecified, accumulated messages will not be included).') ;
    if (typeof config.onAccumulomatorStop !== 'function' && typeof config.onAccumulomatorStop !== 'undefined') throw new Error('If defined at all, onAccumulomatorStop must be a function.') ;

    var sendCallbackAccumulatedMessages = false ;
    if (typeof config.sendCallbackAccumulatedMessages !== 'undefined') sendCallbackAccumulatedMessages = config.sendCallbackAccumulatedMessages ;

    const accumulomatorWarehouse = {} ;


    const accumulomators = {} ;

    var warehouseIsShuttingDown = false ;

    accumulomatorWarehouse.receiveMessage = (message) => {
        accumulomatorName = config.messageRouter(message) ;
        if (typeof accumulomatorName !== 'string') throw new Error('The value returned from messageRouter must be a string with a unique identifier.') ;
        if (typeof accumulomators[accumulomatorName] === 'object') if (accumulomators[accumulomatorName].isActive() === false) delete accumulomators[accumulomatorName] ;
        if (typeof accumulomators[accumulomatorName] === 'undefined') {
            if (warehouseIsShuttingDown === false) accumulomators[accumulomatorName] = makeAccumulomator({
                callback: () => config.callback(
                    (() => {
                        objectToReturn = {} ;
                        objectToReturn.key = accumulomatorName ;
                        if (sendCallbackAccumulatedMessages === true) objectToReturn.messages = accumulomators[accumulomatorName].getAccumulatedMessages() ;
                        return objectToReturn ;
                    })()
                ) ,
                millisecondsBetweenChecks: config.millisecondsBetweenChecks ,
                onStop: () => config.onAccumulomatorStop(accumulomatorName)
            }) ;
        }
        if (typeof accumulomators[accumulomatorName] === 'object') accumulomators[accumulomatorName].receiveMessage(message) ;
    }

    periodicallyRetireAccumulomators = () => {
        Object.keys(accumulomators).forEach((accumulomator) => {
            if (accumulomators[accumulomator].isActive() === false) delete accumulomators[accumulomator] ;
        }) ;
        if (!(warehouseIsShuttingDown === true && Object.keys(accumulomators).length === 0)) setTimeout(periodicallyRetireAccumulomators, 10000) ;
    } ;
    periodicallyRetireAccumulomators() ;

    accumulomatorWarehouse.shutDownWarehouse = () => {
        Object.keys(accumulomators).forEach((accumulomator) => {
            if (accumulomators[accumulomator].isActive() === true) accumulomators[accumulomator].stopOnNextCheck() ;
        }) ;
        warehouseIsShuttingDown = true ;
    }


    return accumulomatorWarehouse ;

}

myAccumulomatorWarehouse = makeAccumulomatorWarehouse({
    callback: (accumulomatorWarehousePackage) => console.log('Done with accumulomator.', accumulomatorWarehousePackage.key, accumulomatorWarehousePackage.messages) ,
    millisecondsBetweenChecks: 2000 ,
    messageRouter: (message) => message ,
    sendCallbackAccumulatedMessages: true ,
    onAccumulomatorStop: (accumulomatorName) => console.log('Accumulomator for ' + accumulomatorName + ' manually stopped')
}) ;

myEmitter.on('event', myAccumulomatorWarehouse.receiveMessage) ;

setTimeout(myAccumulomatorWarehouse.shutDownWarehouse, 10000) ;
```